# Change color of different lines in same layer QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, style, color

Is there a way to manually change color of single lines under the same layer? i know that there's a way to change them via the categorized tab in the layer style properties, but the color change that i need to make doesn't follow any categorization, is just to highlight particular lines. For example i want to change color of a couple lines in the picture, but there is no criteria in the selection of them, just my personal choice.

[image]

Comment: When you select a line, it is highlighted in yellow. You can also change the selection color using "Project > Project Properties > Selection color"

Comment: I believe that the aim is to change the color permanently.

Comment: This is the proper mechanism, just add a column "mycategory" to the layer and set its values for the lines of interest

Comment: Thanks. After i add 'mycategory' column, how do i select the lines which i need to change  color? Because it seems like for a particular color choice i can add a single line value at a time. Is there a way for putting multiple values for the same line color? i dunno maybe separating them by a comma? Sorry for the dumb questions, just started using QGIS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to set your own categories to the lines, then to style each category differently.

For each category, select the lines then open the field calculator. Note that the value will be updated only for the selected lines. Either create the new category field, or update an existing one. Repeat for each category.

[image]

Then style the layer using the `categorized` rendered. Select the `mycategory` field, click `classify` and adjust the colors of each category.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!!! You saved my mental health and my thesis :)

Answer (score 2):

One more feature that could be copied from OpenJUMP into QGIS.

With OpenJUMP you can select some features from a green layer

[image]

and select some other color

[image]

and selected features get colored with the new color. Internally the tool stores the RGB values into an attribute. If the R_G_B attribute has some value it overrides the layer color.

[image]